# oracle client can not display the thai language

Tags: oracle, character-set

I have already set up the oracle client `NLS_LANG=THAI_THAILAND.TH8TISASCII` in `regedit>Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient10g_home1`.

And the database server `CHARACTERSET` also is *TH8TISASCII*`(NLS_CHARACTERSET=TH8TISASCII)`

But SQL PLUS still can't show the thailand language

Answer (score 0):

try to set

> `NLS_LANG`  to the value `AMERICAN_AMERICA.TH8TISASCII`

*we have a similar issue with our local settings that `TURKISH_TURKEY.WE8ISO8859P9` produces problems even if `WE8ISO8859P9` is characterset for Turkish, whereas `AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P9` runs fine for our character set.*

Answer (score 0):

sqlplus inherits the character set from your `cmd.exe`. You can interrogate and modify the character set (aka "codepage") with command `chcp`, e.g.

```
C:\>chcp
Active code page: 1252
```

If you have a Thai Windows then most likely this command returns `Active code page: 874` in your case.

If you get a different code page then change it with `chcp 874` before your launch sqlplus.